# Relative div-Container shall have the height of the absolute img inside it

Tags: html, css, positioning

```
<div id="mainPic" style="width:50%;">
    <img id="pic1" src="#" width="100%">
    <img id="pic2" src="#" width="100%">
</div>
```

I have two images inside a div#mainPic that has a 50% width of his parent. The images will use the full width not more not less and autoscale the height.
The mainPic shall now have the same height like the images.
The problem is that I have to set the images absolute, because I want one above the other. So both have the rules:

```
position : absolute;
top : 0px;
left : 0px;
```

But now the div#mainPic is not dynamicaly having the height from the autoscaled images.
Javascript is also out because JS is setting the height only one time not every time you resize the window.

Comment: Why do you need the 2 images on top of each other? Do you always have only 2 images? Are the 2 images dimensions exactly the same? I can think of a relatively easy fix, but I need to understand this better first.

Comment: @Jayx I wanna make kind of a Diashow. One pic slowly gets the opacity of zero so the other pic below is to see. And again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning sets the position of element relative to the first non-static parent element. You probably haven't set the position of `#mainPic`, which sets it's default value to static. This means if you'll change the position of the child elements `#pic1` and `#pic2` to absolute then they'll be given the position absolute relative to the `body`. This can simply be solved by giving a non-static position to `#mainPic`. 
Example fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thinker3197/n4kn2wLa/

Comment: Well, I have set the position to relative.
But my problem is not really the positioning of #mainPic but of pic1 and pic2, because I want these one above the other. I can do that by giving them an absolute position. Problem the #mainPic has a border and so you can see that the #mainPic does not automatically have the height of the two pics

Comment: Calculate the height and set it dynamically with js -   
    `var picHeight = $('#pic1').height();   
    $('#mainPic').css('height',picHeight);`